# MapR Client for macos m1 chipset

Tags: x86, apple-m1, apple-silicon, mapr, azul-zulu

Hi I have macbook pro m1 and want to install mapr on my computer but currenlty mapr doesn't have apple silicon dmg. When I install x86 based application it gave me below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/mapr/lib/libMapRClient.dylib.1: dlopen(/opt/mapr/lib/libMapRClient.dylib.1, 0x0001): tried: '/opt/mapr/lib/libMapRClient.dylib.1' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/mapr/lib/libMapRClient.dylib.1' (no such file), '/opt/mapr/lib/libMapRClient.dylib.1' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

Any suggestiion what should I do?

Btw I installed java 1.8 for apple silicon from Azul.

Comment: You're mixing arm64 and x86_64. If you want to use x86_64 libraries, you need x86_64 Java.

Comment: No I want to arm64 but mapr doesn't have native arm64 dmg so I downloaded the x86_64 version but it gives me below error. Is there any way to shortcut or any other solution?

Comment: You cannot use x86_64 libraries in an arm64 process. You need x86_64 Java.

Comment: I changed the java version with x86_64 based and it worked thank you very much